# angularjs foreach on a geojson object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want how to access particular values with forEach of angularjs, in a geojson object

see code and error :

my geojson :

```
var Field = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point"     },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "test": "tge",
            "test2": "tge"

        },
        "fiche": {
            "id": "1",
            "date_creation": "2014-04-01 00:00:00",
            "date_modification": "2014-04-01 00:00:00"
        },
        },

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point"     },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "test": "gztgt",
            "test2": "gztgt"
        },
        "fiche": {
            "id": "2",
            "date_creation": "2014-04-01 00:00:00",
            "date_modification": "2014-04-01 00:00:00"
        },
        },
    ]
};
```

js code (in controller) :

```
    /* scope alternate view */
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDataLocalIntern}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        eval(data);
        $scope.alternateViewText = Field.features[];


    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error ");
    });
```

html code :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="alternate in alternateViewText">
        <p>{{alternate.properties.test}} - {{alternate.properties.test2}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when i do this i have this error

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/ng/areq?p0=MapCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

what's wrong ?

Comment: Follow the error link, it clearly states that you have a problem with your controller. `MapCtrl is not a function, got undefined`.

Comment: when i remove the $http, controller works; why the error said there is an error outside $http part ?

Comment: It's hard to tell by the code snippets you have posted. Try to post the whole controller declaration. Also a jsfiddle with your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MapCntrl is not defined. Can u post a jsfiddle link or something with the whole snippet?

Ps.: don't use eval(), because it's not secure. Go with JSON.parse() instead.